# Vue JS alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to VueJS.
I had written an alert box using jquery. Now I'm trying to provide that in VueJS.
Here is what I have done:

1- Created a component named **NovinAlert.vue** including:

```
<template>
    <div id="novin-alert-container">
        <div v-for="message in messages" class="alert novin-alert" :class="message.class">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            {{ message.body }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                messages: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            novinAlert: function (message) {
                let app = this;
                message.type = typeof message.type !== 'undefined' ? message.type : 'info';
                message.class = 'alert' + message.type;
                let index = app.messages.push(message) - 1;
                if (typeof message.duration !== 'undefined') {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        app.messages.splice(index, 1);
                    }, message.duration * 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

2- My example component is **Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            novinAlert('test');
        }
    }
</script>
```

3- My main **layout** is:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <novin-alert></novin-alert>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

4- And this is my **app.js**:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
window.Vue.use(VueRouter);
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue';
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Dashboard, name: 'dashboard'},
];
import NovinAlert from './components/utils/NovinAlert.vue';
Vue.component('novin-alert', NovinAlert);
const router = new VueRouter({ routes: routes });
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app'
});
```

When I run dashboard page, it doesn't know `novinAlert` function.
What I have done wrong? And what is best practice for what I'm trying to do?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I finally did:
I created an instance of *Vue* in my `app.js`:

```
window.eventBus = new Vue();
```

I use this event but for multiple purposes. Whenever I need I trigger(emit) an event and the listener does required action.

For alert box, I emit the event like this:

```
window.eventBus.$emit('alert', {
    text: app.trans('general.error_in_reading_data'),
    type: 'danger',
    duration: 5,
});
```

Then my alert component reacts like this:

```
mounted() {
    window.eventBus.$on('alert', (message) => {
        this.novinAlert(message);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2):

i've designed a **SIMPLE** popup right now with Vuejs 2.* and it works well. 
 In this example, popup is included as a Local component. This would be one of the **best practices** to follow. Let me know if this helps.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Main page</div>
    <button @click="openpopup">Open popup</button>
    <popup :popupData="popupData" ></popup>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Popup from'./Popup.vue';
  export default {
    components:{
      "popup" : Popup
    },
    data() {
      return {
        popupData : {
          "header" : "My popup",
          "body" : "hello world",
          "footer" : "divine inc.",
          "display" : "none"
        }
      }
    },
    methods : {
      openpopup(){
        this.popupData.display = "block";
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.popupData.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Popup.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="popup" :style="{display : popupData.display}">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="header">
            <div>{{popupData.header}}</div>
            <div @click="closeFunction">Close</div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">{{popupData.body}}</div>
        <div class="footer">{{popupData.footer}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props : ["popupData"],
    methods : {
        closeFunction(){
            this.popupData.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
#popup{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height :100%;
    top: 0;
}
#popup .inner{
    background-color: green;
    position: inherit;
    top: 10%;
    left: 39%;
    width: 300px;
}
#popup .inner div{
    text-align: left;
}
#popup .inner .header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @divine. You mean its better to import the alert component in any component I want to use rather than making the alert component as global so that all components could use it? Doesn't this make the code WET (not DRY)?

Comment: @AliFarhoudi you may need to re-use this same AlertPopup functionality for different Scenarios in your website. And different scenario's may require different text messages in popup and some pages may not need popup. If this is the case,then personally, i feel,  using popup component as a local component would be a better approach

Comment: You have defined ```openPopUp``` function in your component. But I don't want to do that. I want to call method inside another component. I tried your code but can't call a method defined in popup.vue inside app.vue's mounted section.

Comment: @AliFarhoudi why do you want to do that?

Comment: @AliFarhoudi i recommend to pass processed raw data's to components like Popup.vue. Thereby it becomes lightweight and low coupling is achieved

Answer (score 1):

You can't access one component's method from another. you need to move the `novinAlert` function to the `Dashboard` component and pass messages as a property to `NovinAlert` component:

**NovinAlert.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="novin-alert-container">
        <div v-for="message in messages" class="alert novin-alert" :class="message.class">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            {{ message.body }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
       props: ['messages']
    }

</script>
```

**Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    <!-- pass the messages prop to the component -->
    <novin-alert :messages="messages"></novin-alert>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.novinAlert('test');
        },
 data() {
    return {
        messages: []
    }
 },
 methods: {
            novinAlert: function (message) {
                let app = this;
                message.type = typeof message.type !== 'undefined' ? message.type : 'info';
                message.class = 'alert' + message.type;
                let index = app.messages.push(message) - 1;
                if (typeof message.duration !== 'undefined') {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        app.messages.splice(index, 1);
                    }, message.duration * 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

if you want the novin alert in the app level, you'll need to pass the function to the app component

Comment: Thanks fatman. I don't think that is a good idea. Because I need this function in many other components. It's not good to copy it in every component. I thinks importing component in other components as @divine said could be a better solution. What do you think?

Comment: Put it in a separate module (js file) and import it where ever you need. or use a mixin: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html